# How to revert a file from repository with GIT in AndroidStudio

Tags: git, android-studio

I try to get a file from the GIT repository to my local AndroidStudio project, respectivly I would like to do a simple revert. I don't find a revert option and a Hardreset does absolutely nothing.

How can I do this ?

Can someone guide me to all the steps needed ? In Eclipse it was simple the revert option.

Comment: Revert shortcut in Windows: ctrl + alt + z. There's a purple arrow icon. If you've told Android Studio that the project has VCS. I don't remember the exact steps for that though.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late but hope this will help others. To find `Revert` option in `Android Studio` using `VCS` just do this:

1. Go to `VCS => Local History => Show History`[image]
2. Then click the `Revert` button in Upper left Corner[image]

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

As a user has described in comments on your question you can revert with the `Ctrl+Alt+z` keyboard command.

You can also right click a file in the project structure and revert.

Alternatively you can open `VCS --> VCS Operations Dialog`, Revert.

You can also revert by opening the commit dialog using any of the following:

- `VCS --> Commit Changes`
- `Ctrl+K`/`CMD+K`

then right click a file and revert